# Diameter and radius of complete graph

Tags: graph-theory

Can some one help me Find the diameter and radius of complete graph with n vertices, I know how to do it for complete graph with small number of vertices but can generalize to the one with n vertices.

Comment: Start by writing out the definitions of diameter and radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an (unweighted) graph. The eccentricity of a vertex $v\in V$ is $\varepsilon (v)=\max_{u\in V} d(u,v)$. The radius $r$ of $G$ is the minimum eccentricity of the vertices, i.e. $r = \min_{v\in V}\varepsilon(v) = \min_{v\in V}\max_{u\in V}d(u,v)$. The diameter $d$ of $G$ is the maximum eccentricity of the vertices, that is, $d = \max_{v\in V}\varepsilon(v)$.

If $G$ is a complete graph, then $uv\in E$ for all $u,v\in V$, and so $\varepsilon(v)=1$ for all $v\in V$. It follows immediately that the radius and diameter are both one.